Getting content from several table pages from a website
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Navigate to the page
  await page.goto('https://www.sharkscope.com/#Find-Tournament//networks/888Poker(ES-PT)/tournaments/252404158');

  // Wait for the first selector to be available
  let selectorIndex = 1;
  const extractedContent = {};

  while (true) {
    const selector = `#jqg${selectorIndex}`;
    const selectorExists = await page.waitForSelector(`${selector} > td:nth-child(5)`, { timeout: 1000 }).then(() => true).catch(() => false);

    if (!selectorExists) break;

    // Extract information from the selector
    extractedContent[selector] = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
      const element = document.querySelector(`${sel} > td:nth-child(5)`);
      return element ? element.textContent.trim() : null;
    }, selector);

    selectorIndex++;
  }

  // Print the extracted information
  console.log('Extracted content:', extractedContent);

  await browser.close();
})();

I'm using this javascript to extract information form 5 column in every row of the table (prizes content). But the log only shows the first 25 entries because the table have several pages... Can someone help me to get into the other table pages? Thanks!
Here is the log content:
Extracted content: {
  '#jqg1': '€323  (Bounties: €64.28)',
  '#jqg2': '€273  (Bounties: €83.56)',
  '#jqg3': '€244  (Bounties: €105)',
  '#jqg4': '€227  (Bounties: €124)',
  '#jqg5': '€189  (Bounties: €121)',
  '#jqg6': '€47.9',
  '#jqg7': '€172  (Bounties: €138)',
  '#jqg8': '€86.77  (Bounties: €62.82)',
  '#jqg9': '€26.89  (Bounties: €8.55)',
  '#jqg10': '€22.62  (Bounties: €4.28)',
  '#jqg11': '€26.9  (Bounties: €8.56)',
  '#jqg12': '€268  (Bounties: €250)',
  '#jqg13': '€89.01  (Bounties: €75.32)',
  '#jqg14': '€22.97  (Bounties: €9.28)',
  '#jqg15': '€13.69',
  '#jqg16': '€57.96  (Bounties: €44.27)',
  '#jqg17': '€15.5  (Bounties: €4.28)',
  '#jqg18': '€11.22',
  '#jqg19': '€36.22  (Bounties: €25)',
  '#jqg20': '€30.5  (Bounties: €19.28)',
  '#jqg21': '€21.22  (Bounties: €10)',
  '#jqg22': '€11.22',
  '#jqg23': '€11.22',
  '#jqg24': '€11.22',
  '#jqg25': '€13.9  (Bounties: €5)'
}

I find the selector to next page button of the table, and try to incorporate that in the code for clicking and extract the content next but doesn't work. Your I'm doing something wrong

It seams that they don't allow deep linking to paginated lists. And they are probably not interested in people scraping their website.

It is strange since you can consult that information on a regular browser, I'm just trying to extract the information with javascript to be more automatic
